# Difference between \input and \include

Tags: external-files

Difference between `\input{filename}` and `\input{filename}` in the main tex file.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working on big documents, you might want to split the input file into
several parts. **LaTeX** has two commands that help you to do that.

```
\include{filename}
```

Use this command in the document body to insert the contents of another file
named filename.tex.

Note that LATEX will start a new page before processing
the material input from filename.tex.
The second command can be used in the preamble. It allows you to
instruct LATEX to only input some of the \included files.

```
\includeonly{filename,filename,…}
```

After this command is executed in the preamble of the document, only
`\include` commands for the filenames that are listed in the argument of the
`\includeonly` command will be executed.
The \include command starts typesetting the included text on a new
page. This is helpful when you use `\includeonly`, because the page breaks
will not move, even when some include files are omitted. Sometimes this
might not be desirable.

In this case, use the `\input{filename}` command. It simply includes the file specified. No flashy suits, no strings
attached.